# Is there an Android API to get the external color of the device?

Tags: android

Is there an API to get the external color of the device?  I can't find this functionality and I'm not sure that it exits, but I thought I would throw it out there and see if anyone else knows?

For instance, if my application is running on a GS7, I want to know if it's white, black, gold or silver.

Comment: Why would the software care about the color of the device? It's like trying to write code for "is there a case on my device"

Comment: Also, some devices have replaceable backplates and the like.

Comment: Can you see the back of your head?

Comment: Android does not provide an API for that. Maybe (if you only want the feature to be compatible with your GS7) you could research if the color depends on the model number https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL

Comment: The only correlation between the model number and the device description seems to be a high level model description and service provider.  It does not seem to be linked to storage size or external color.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is. As far as I know, the Android OS doesn't have an internal representation of what color the current device is. Quite simply - it's outside the scope of information that the software needs, and therefor it's never bothered to be represented at the software level.

*However*: You may be able to rely on external APIs.

If you had to find this information, you could either:

1. Prompt the User, or
2. Use the device's unique serial, and utilize an
   external API to pull a list of **possible** colors that were
   manufactured for that device.

Regardless, neither solution would be particularly elegant.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  This is part of a work task that is essentially tied into an automated inventory system of sorts.  While stores may very well have a list of associations between serial numbers and device details, there may not be an API to access this data.

I'm going to explore manufacturer APIs and see if there is anything out there.